# Accidentally delete ibdata1, ib_logfile1 and ib_logfile0

Tags: mysql, mysql5.5

Actually i have problems with the database always down due to log. Usually when I restart it will work just fine. But recently the database cannot start and make me think to simply delete those mention file. At first I thought it's ok after delete the files because mySql can run as usual but i just found out that I lost my wordpress database. Upon checking mysql admin console, I can see all the tables are there. But I cannot perform any queries on it. How do I get back those missing tables as well as the data.

Comment: The ibdata1 file contained the actual data. You will need to restore from a backup.

Comment: depends. there’s a mode when innodb stores each table in separate files.

Answer (score 2):

The ibdata files contain some of your InnoDB table data. Removing them has likely rendered the InnoDB data within your tables corrupt.

At this stage you should probably look into restoring a backup. Alternatively you could try to recover the data with `extundelete`, or similar tools for data recovery.

Answer (score 1):

You should reach for your backups and restore from them. If you don't have backups then you could try [undeleting](https://serverfault.com/search?q=linux%20recover%20deleted%20file) the files but make a copy of the disk (using dd) and work on that.